# Remove reference ruler under abstract using ACM template

Tags: header-footer, acm, acmart

Using ACM `acmart` template, I can use `\settopmatter{printacmref=false}` to remove the reference under abstract, but there are two ruler lines still lingering, see the image below. Any idea how I can get rid of them? TIA

```
\documentclass[review=false,screen,manuscript]{acmart}
\settopmatter{printacmref=false} % Removes citation information below abstract
\renewcommand\footnotetextcopyrightpermission[1]{} % removes footnote with conference info
\setcopyright{none}
\pagestyle{plain} % remove running headers
\usepackage{blindtext}

\title{TBD}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\blindtext[1]
\end{document}
```

[image: sample]

Answer (score 1):

Other people complained too.  So a design change was made: in the current version of `acmart` there are no rules around abstract.